Sorting Checkbox columns from Datatable
I have a datatable in which I added several checkbox columns. I want to be able to sort my columns according to the values of the checkboxes (checked or not). I tested a lot of different things and found one portion of code which seems to work, but sadly does not. That's the solution proposed here : R/Shiny - Scrollable datatable with checkboxes and total count.
What I observed is that when you arrive on the app and you check the boxes then filter there is no problem. But if you try to update then the checkboxes it keeps the sorting from before.
Example of problem with checkboxes:

To reproduce this example, here is the code :
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      6,
      DTOutput("dtable")
    ),
    column(
      6,
      verbatimTextOutput("reactiveDF")
    )
  )
)

checkboxColumn <- function(len, col, ...) { # `col` is the column index
  inputs <- character(len)
  for(i in seq_len(len)) {
    inputs[i] <- as.character(
      checkboxInput(paste0("checkb_", col, "_", i), label = NULL, ...)
    )
  }
  inputs
}

dat0 <- data.frame(
  fruit  = c("apple", "cherry", "pineapple", "pear"),
  letter = c("a", "b", "c", "d")
)

dat1 <- cbind(dat0, bool1 = FALSE, bool2 = FALSE)

dat2 <- cbind(
  dat0,
  check1 = checkboxColumn(nrow(dat0), 3),
  check2 = checkboxColumn(nrow(dat0), 4)
)

js <- function(dtid, cols, ns = identity) {
  code <- vector("list", length(cols))
  for(i in seq_along(cols)) {
    col <- cols[i]
    code[[i]] <- c(
      sprintf(
        "$('body').on('click', '[id^=checkb_%d_]', function() {",
        col),
      "  var id = this.getAttribute('id');",
      sprintf(
        "  var i = parseInt(/checkb_%d_(\\d+)/.exec(id)[1]);",
        col),
      "  var value = $(this).prop('checked');",
      sprintf(
        "  var info = [{row: i, col: %d, value: value}];",
        col),
      sprintf(
        "  Shiny.setInputValue('%s', info);",
        ns(sprintf("%s_cell_edit:DT.cellInfo", dtid))
      ),
      "});"
    )
  }
  do.call(c, code)
}

checkboxesColumns <- c(3, 4)

render <- function(col) { 
sprintf('
function(data, type, row, meta) {
  if(type == "sort") { 
    var i = meta.row + 1;
    var $box = $("#checkb_%d_" + i);
    data = $box.prop("checked") ? "true" : "false";
  }
  return data;
}', col)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Dat <- reactiveVal(dat1)
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      dat2, 
      rownames = TRUE,
      escape = FALSE,
      editable = list(
        target = "cell", disable = list(columns = checkboxesColumns)
      ),
      selection = "none",
      callback = JS(js("dtable", checkboxesColumns)), 
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
         list(targets = 3, render = JS(render(3))),
         list(targets = 4, render = JS(render(4)))
        )
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input[["dtable_cell_edit"]], { 
    info <- input[["dtable_cell_edit"]] # this input contains the info of the edit
    Dat(editData(Dat(), info))
  })
  
  output[["reactiveDF"]] <- renderPrint({ 
    Dat()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Is there any solution to that?

Share a minimal reproducible example of the problem. This includes code and relevant data. That is the only way you can get help here on Stack Overflow.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The idea is that we define an invisible numeric column for each checkbox column which contains the values 0 or 1 depending on whether the checkbox in the corresponding cell is checked, and that we use these numeric columns for ordering the checkbox columns using orderData.

library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      6,
      DTOutput("dtable")
    ),
    column(
      6,
      verbatimTextOutput("reactiveDF")
    )
  )
)

checkboxColumn <- function(len, col, ...) { # `col` is the column index
  inputs <- character(len)
  for(i in seq_len(len)) {
    inputs[i] <- as.character(
      checkboxInput(paste0("checkb_", col, "_", i), label = NULL, ...)
    )
  }
  inputs
}

dat0 <- data.frame(
  fruit  = c("apple", "cherry", "pineapple", "pear"),
  letter = c("a", "b", "c", "d")
)

dat2 <- cbind(
  dat0,
  check1 = checkboxColumn(nrow(dat0), 3),
  check2 = checkboxColumn(nrow(dat0), 4),
  dummy1 = 0,
  dummy2 = 0
)

checkboxesColumns <- c(3, 4)

render <- function(col) { 
  sprintf('
function(data, type, row, meta) {
  if(type == "sort") { 
    var i = meta.row + 1;
    var $box = $("#checkb_%d_" + i);
    data = $box.prop("checked") ? "true" : "false";
  }
  return data;
}', col)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      dat2, 
      rownames = TRUE,
      escape = FALSE,
      editable = list(
        target = "cell", disable = list(columns = checkboxesColumns)
      ),
      selection = "none",
      callback = JS(
        c(
          "table.on('click', 'tbody td',", 
          "  function () {",
          "    var rowIndex = table.row(this).index();",
          "    var colIndex = table.column(this).index();",
          "    var $box = $('#checkb_' + colIndex + '_' + (rowIndex + 1));",
          "    var checkBoxState = $box.prop('checked') ? 1 : 0;",
          "    table.cell({",
          "      row: rowIndex,",
          "      column: colIndex + 2",
          "    }).data(checkBoxState).draw();",
          "  })"
          )
        ),
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
          list(targets = 3, render = JS(render(3)), orderData = 5),
          list(targets = 4, render = JS(render(4)), orderData = 6),
          list(targets = 5, visible = FALSE),
          list(targets = 6, visible = FALSE)
        )
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Works perfectly! I just added back the reactiveVal because I needed it, and concatenate the 2 callbacks, so I do have the values and I am able to sort them :)
